# Is there any good slide show that allows you to easily put in custom HTML on each slide

Tags: jquery, html, slideshow

I am looking for a good jquery slide show that allows you to put in custom code. Please note that the custom code is very important. What i mean by custom code is, You have the regular slide show, and each slide has a picture with custom HTML code like buttons, lables, and other html elements. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery Cycle is pretty good. It's really good for images but you can also add divs with HTML in as well. It's very customisable and well documented. For good HTML div examples see the bottom of this page - http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html

Comment: Can I get an explanation for the down vote? Perfectly valid answer.

Comment: Agreed, cycle is perfectly valid for this. +1 to even things up a bit

Comment: Thanks Clive. This down voting without giving a reason is a bit frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://slidesjs.com/
The slides are enclosed in DIV elements, and you can put whatever you want inside

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you mean by a 'slide show', but perhaps [Orbit](http://www.zurb.com/playground/orbit-jquery-image-slider) might be what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Mike Alsup's [jQuery Cycle Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK ,slides.js supports only images sildeshows . Use Cycle plugin instead.